# Data Tables Get iDataRow in mRender

Tags: jquery, datatables, render

I am using [DataTables](http://datatables.net/ref) and the [TableTools](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/)

It is possible get row index in mRender? Something like this:

```
{
"mData": "someData",
"mRender" :  function ( data, type, full ) {
     **// get iDataRow somehow**
     return '<a href="'+data+'">Download '+ **iDataRow** +'</a>';
   }
}
```

- and not alter data for return of iDataRow

suggestions?

Comment: Use DataTable 1.10 columns.render : function ( data, type, full, meta ) { ... }, meta.row is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

> Allan: This feature (columns.render) is available starting from **May 2014, DataTable 1.10
>   release**. "...columns.data, columns.render should be able to do
>   anything fnRender could do".

The evolution chain of the datatable render feature:

1. fnRender (deprecated)
2. mRender
3. columns.render (the latest, most powerful)

Example: [columns.render - Use as a function to create a link from the data source](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render).

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
   "columnDefs": [ {
   "targets": 0,
    "data": "download_link",
    "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) { //meta.row is what you are looking for
      var ix = meta.row;
      return "Row number is " + ix;
    }
  } ]
} );
```

Here are two related **unanswered** questions from datatable forum, but the first contains the references which helped me to find out the answer:

- [How to get row index in mData, June 2013](https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/16059/how-to-get-row-index-in-mdata)
- [Get row index in mRender, December 2012](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/13279/get-row-index-in-mrender)

Answer (score 0):

```
 "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
     return "<a href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Review")?id=" + row.ReviewId + "'" + " Class='label label-sm label-success deleteLink loader' >Active</a>";
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if you mean you want to get information of certain rows when you mean `iDataRow`.

```
{
"mData": "someData",
"mRender" :  function (data, type, full, row) {
        // * *  get iDataRow somehow**
                return '<a href="' + data + '">Download ' + row[0] + '</a>'; // Row[0] = first column first row data
        }
}
```

Good luck with the implementation